# Help me tune my.conf MySQL

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-8.0

Currently, I have been surfing around for ideas and copying some of the processes and details found and playing around with my Server and now seems to be pretty good but with some anomalies in performance (not always)...
if you see something wrong with my current configuration which could tend to decrease the performance of the server instead of improving it please let me know and thanks for reading and helping

I'm attaching my conf file used in

**OS**

> Virtualization: vmware
> Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
> CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
> Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64
> Architecture: x86-64

**Resources**

> Ram 64GB ECC DDR3 - CPU 2 Cores 8 Logic Processors per core = 16 - Disk Nvme m.2 500GB Samsung 980Pro

**MySQL 8.0.22**

```
[mysqld_safe]
log_error                                       = /var/log/mysql_error.log
[mysqld]
# datadir = {{ mysqldir }}
datadir                                         = /var/lib/mysql
socket                                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# Datadog
general_log                                     = ON
general_log_file                                = /var/log/mysqld.log
log_error                                       = /var/log/mysql_error.log
slow_query_log                                  = ON
slow_query_log_file                             = /var/log/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time                                 = 1
log_output                                      = File
log_queries_not_using_indexes                   = ON
local-infile                                    = ON
character_set_server                            = utf8mb4
collation_server                                = utf8mb4_general_ci
default_authentication_plugin                   = mysql_native_password
skip-character-set-client-handshake
# current configuration 
skip-name-resolve                               = 1
sql-mode                                        = ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
ssl-ca                                          = ca.pem
ssl-cert                                        = server-cert.pem
ssl-key                                         = server-key.pem
require_secure_transport                        = ON
# general
table_definition_cache                          = 400000
back_log                                        = 3500
# tune
max_seeks_for_key                               = 32
max_connections                                 = 100
connect_timeout                                 = 5
wait_timeout                                    = 600
net_read_timeout                                = 60
max_allowed_packet                              = 160M
thread_cache_size                               = 128
bulk_insert_buffer_size                         = 16M
tmp_table_size                                  = 16M
max_heap_table_size                             = 16M
sort_buffer_size                                = 4M
read_buffer_size                                = 2M
join_buffer_size                                = 512k
read_rnd_buffer_size                            = 512K
key_buffer_size                                 = 6M
myisam_recover_options                          = BACKUP
myisam_sort_buffer_size                         = 16M
table_open_cache                                = 400000
table_open_cache_instances                      = 8
concurrent_insert                               = 2
max_binlog_size                                 = 100M
thread_stack                                    = 4M
max_prepared_stmt_count                         = 1000000
performance_schema                              = ON
binlog_expire_logs_seconds                      = 864000
innodb_log_files_in_group                       = 2
innodb_undo_log_truncate                        = OFF
innodb_doublewrite                              = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit                  = 0
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                      = 90
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm                  = 10
innodb_page_cleaners                            = 4
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay                 = 10000
innodb_lru_scan_depth                           = 128
innodb_io_capacity                              = 40000
innodb_io_capacity_max                          = 80000
innodb_purge_threads                            = 4
innodb_flushing_avg_loops                       = 4
innodb_thread_concurrency                       = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances                    = 32
innodb_log_file_size                            = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size                          = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_size                         = 30G
innodb_change_buffer_max_size                   = 50
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                   = 512M
innodb_file_per_table                           = 1
innodb_open_files                               = 600
innodb_flush_method                             = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_flush_neighbors                          = 0
innodb_write_io_threads                         = 64
innodb_read_io_threads                          = 64
innodb_use_native_aio                           = 1
innodb_adaptive_hash_index                      = 0
innodb_stats_persistent                         = 1
innodb_adaptive_flushing                        = 1
innodb_monitor_enable                           = '%'
```

**Update**

I have been evaluating my processes and settings step by step with the log files and a lot of reading, so far this set up is working very well and way Faster than the one before...
Now the Inserts, Delete and Read goes from Hours to even 1 minute with no CPU Spikes or RAM
Looking Forward what you guys think I could adjust -
Thanks

```
[mysqld_safe]
log_error                                       = /var/log/mysql_error.log
[mysqld]
# datadir = {{ mysqldir }}
datadir                                         = /var/lib/mysql
socket                                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# Datadog
#general_log                                     = ON
#general_log_file                                = /var/log/mysqld.log
log_error                                       = /var/log/mysql_error.log
slow_query_log                                  = ON
slow_query_log_file                             = /var/log/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time                                 = 1
log_output                                      = File
log_queries_not_using_indexes                   = ON
local-infile                                    = ON
character_set_server                            = utf8mb4
collation_server                                = utf8mb4_general_ci
default_authentication_plugin                   = mysql_native_password
skip-character-set-client-handshake
# current configuration 
skip-name-resolve                               = 1
sql-mode                                        = ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
ssl-ca                                          = ca.pem
ssl-cert                                        = server-cert.pem
ssl-key                                         = server-key.pem
require_secure_transport                        = ON
# general
#table_definition_cache                          = 400000
#back_log                                        = 3500
# tune
#max_seeks_for_key                               = 32
max_connections                                 = 100
#connect_timeout                                 = 5
#wait_timeout                                    = 600
#net_read_timeout                                = 60
#max_allowed_packet                              = 160M
#thread_cache_size                               = 128
bulk_insert_buffer_size                         = 256M
tmpdir                                          = /dev/shm
tmp_table_size                                  = 256M
max_heap_table_size                             = 256M
sort_buffer_size                                = 50M
read_buffer_size                                = 4M
join_buffer_size                                = 3M
read_rnd_buffer_size                            = 8M
innodb_sort_buffer_size                         = 50M
key_buffer_size                                 = 50M
#myisam_recover_options                          = BACKUP
#myisam_sort_buffer_size                         = 16M
table_open_cache                                = 40000
#table_open_cache_instances                      = 8
#concurrent_insert                               = 2
#max_binlog_size                                 = 100M
#thread_stack                                    = 4M
#max_prepared_stmt_count                         = 1000000
performance_schema                              = 1
binlog_expire_logs_seconds                      = 864000
innodb_log_files_in_group                       = 2
#innodb_undo_log_truncate                        = OFF
#innodb_doublewrite                              = 0
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit                  = 0
#innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                      = 90
#innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm                  = 10
#innodb_page_cleaners                            = 4
#innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay                 = 10000
innodb_lru_scan_depth                           = 5196
innodb_io_capacity                              = 1000
#innodb_io_capacity_max                          = 2000
#innodb_purge_threads                            = 4
#innodb_flushing_avg_loops                       = 4
innodb_thread_concurrency                       = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances                    = 2
innodb_log_file_size                            = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size                          = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size                         = 2G
#innodb_change_buffer_max_size                   = 50
#innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                   = 512M
#innodb_file_per_table                           = 1
#innodb_open_files                               = 600
innodb_flush_method                             = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
#innodb_flush_neighbors                          = 0
innodb_write_io_threads                         = 16
innodb_read_io_threads                          = 16
#innodb_use_native_aio                           = 1
innodb_adaptive_hash_index                      = 1
#innodb_stats_persistent                         = 1
#innodb_adaptive_flushing                        = 1
innodb_monitor_enable                           = '%'
#innodb_dedicated_server = ON
```

Comment: Well, the idea of my question is. if you see something wrong with my current configuration which could tend to decrease the performance of the server instead of improving it.

Comment: Go back to the default my.cnf.  Your changes have hurt more than helped.

Comment: @carloslozada  Your  https://www.lookyourbike.com/ appears to be down this morning with error 521 reported from CloudFlare.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little good news for you

## ASPECT #1

You could tune certain aspect of MySQL 8.0 with just one option: [innodb_dedicated_server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_dedicated_server).

The [innodb_dedicated_server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_dedicated_server) options will auto-tune four(4) things

[innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size):

- Less than 1G: 128M (default value if innodb_dedicated_server is OFF)
- Less Than or = 4G: Detected Physical RAM * 0.5
- Greater than 4G: Detected Physical RAM * 0.75

[innodb_log_file_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size):

- Less than 1G: 48M (default value if innodb_dedicated_server is OFF)
- Less then 4G: 128M
- Less than<=8G: 512M
- <=16G: 1024M
- Greater than 16G: 2G

The variable also sets the following:

[innodb_flush_method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method):

- Set to O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC if the setting is available on the system.
- If not, set it to the default InnoDB flush method

[innodb_log_file_in_group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_files_in_group) (as of MySQL 8.0.14) : The number of log files in the log group. InnoDB writes to the files in a circular fashion. The default (and recommended) value is 2. The location of the files is specified by innodb_log_group_home_dir. The combined size of log files (innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group) can be up to 512GB.

## ASPECT #2

You can lower [innodb_read_io_threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [innodb_write_io_threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) to 16 for now.

Periodically, you should run [SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-engine.html)\G

Check for the expression `Pending normal aio` and you will see something like

```
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
```

If any of the zeros become very high (like 16-32) frequently, then increase one or both of them.

## ASPECT #3

Your [innodb_log_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) needs to be like 32M not 3G.

## ASPECT #4

Your [innodb_adaptive_hash_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_adaptive_hash_index) should be enabled

## ASPECT #5

All other tuning aspect would be the same as you would for MySQL 5.7. You can refer to this Percona blog for those aspects => [MySQL 5.7 Performance Tuning After Installation](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/). You can also refer to other posts in the DBA StackExchange. [You should definitely read all the options for innodb from the MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html).

## HAVE FUN RESEARCHING !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are *vastly* over-tuning. By default you shouldn't be touching anything other than `innodb_buffer_pool_size` unless your workload specifically requires a deviation from defaults, which are sensible for the majority of workloads.

Changing `sort_buffer_size` and `join_buffer_size` away from defaults is particularly counter-productive in virtually all cases. `innodb_open_files` should be left alone as it defaults to `table_open_cache` - which you have set absurdly high.

Your `innodb_io_capacity` is also almost certainly set to more than your SSDs can realistically deliver on a database workload with 16KB blocks, especially since you also have `general_log` enabled. Instead, you would be better off disabling `general_log` and only leaving `slow_log` enabled with `long_query_time=0` set.

Comment: Leave `long_query_time` at `1`; catch some of the worst queries; then lower it.  Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the log.

Comment: @RickJames, really, you would advise not doing away with general_log and using just the `slow_log` with `long_query_time=0`? What's the reasoning?

Comment: I was agreeing with you, except for the long_query_time.  The general_log consumes a lot of disk and seems like overkill; hence I rarely recommend it.  The slowlog is useful for finding the "worst" queries.  The not-so-bad queries usually don't matter.

Comment: @RickJames ah, right. My reasoning was that general long AND slow log was redundant, so instead of both it's better to have just slow log at threshold 0 rather than both general log and slow log at higher threshold.

Comment: `long_query_time = 0` captures all statements (I think).

Comment: Yes, exactly - just like the general log. Hence it functionally becomes a replacement for general log at `long_query_time=0`. And since general_log is enabled in the provided config snippet...

Comment: Wow, Thanks so much for the output, as I mentioned before, My intention is to be able to set up this server as good as possible that can handle anything I can throw at it, setting up the server with `innodb_dedicated_server = ON` and figuring out the rest later was how I started but then a long the way I get lost with so many options so Thanks for the `long_query_time = 0` and the `general_log = 0` logic makes a lot of sense

Comment: No one single configuration will make things best at "anything you can throw at it". You need to optimize for your specific usage, and most of the defaults are reasonable for typical usage.

Comment: Thanks @GordanBobic I'm starting from 0 one more time and analysing the response of the server.

Comment: @carloslozada When you chose to install 8.0.22 that became GA about 6 days ago, you are automatically the person who assumes Bug Reporting duties.  If you have time, that is fine.  In the future, you may consider allowing someone else this privilege by installing a version that has at least 90 days since General Availability.  By then most serious problems have been resolved with a newer version.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Hi, Thanks for that note very important indeed. I will report any bug if any :) I have been "playing" as my wife will agree... all this weekend with the conf files and so far it's looking very good from Hours of processes to just even 1 minute
**No heavy load on the CPU or RAM and very Fast Processes**
````

````